# Uniform Convergence involving Exponentials

Tags: real-analysis

I am given $f_n(x)=\frac{n^2x+e^{nx}-1}{e^{2nx}}$ and I have found it is pointwise convergent to $f(x)=0$ on $[0,\infty)$. The question I have is to prove that $f_n(x)$ converges uniformly to $f(x)$ on $[a,\infty)$ for some $a>0$. I tried using the uniform norm and triangle inequality to show that $$\sup{f_n(x)} \le \sup{ \left| \frac{n^2x}{e^{2nx}} \right| + \left| \frac{e^{nx}-1}{e^{2nx}} \right|}$$

It is obvious the second term decays naturally but I ran into issues with the first term. Is there a different method I could take to approach this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We have \begin{align}\left|f_n(x)\right|&\leq \frac{n^2x}{e^{2nx}}+\frac{e^{nx}}{e^{2nx}}+\frac{1}{e^{2nx}}\\
& = \frac{n^2x}{e^{2nx}}+\frac{1}{e^{nx}}+\frac{1}{e^{2nx}}\\
& \leq \frac{n^2x}{e^{2nx}}+\frac{1}{e^{na}}+\frac{1}{e^{2na}}.\end{align}
For the first the term, you have $$e^{2nx}=1+2nx+\frac{1}{2}(2nx)^2+\frac{1}{6}(2nx)^3+\cdots,$$
so in particular $e^{2nx}\geq \frac{8}{6}(nx)^3$. Hence $$\frac{n^2x}{e^{2nx}}\leq \frac{3}{4nx^2}\leq \frac{3}{4na^2},$$
and you're done.